# Entity Framework & Multitables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq to entity expression:

```
entities = new zdmEntities();
var reltables = (from r in entities.relations
                       orderby r.id
                       select new Relation
                       {
                           Id = r.id,
                           Devices = r.devices.device_name,
                           Systems = r.systems.system_name,
                           Models = r.models.name,
                           Functions = r.functions.function_name
                       }).ToList();


 ultraGrid1.DataSource = reltables.ToList();



class Relation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Devices { get; set; }
        public string Systems { get; set; }
        public string Models { get; set; }
        public string Functions { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see the relation table contains a link to other tables.

The class Relation contains my columns for the datagrid. 
But there is one problem... can't be posssible two way databinding between grid and database. I wrote all the updates manually but it's very difficult. 
I understand that this is because in linq expression there is 'new'. But how do you make it without 'new'?

How I can display columns that I need with a two-way databinding and without own class like 'Relation'.
Windows Form. Not wpf)

Thanx, Alex.

Comment: Why can't you bind to the existing `Relations` class?

Comment: So `r.devices` isn't really a list of devices as its name would suggest, but rather a single device (since you're selecting `r.devices.device_name`)?

Comment: relation table contains device_id,model_id... columns. linq lets me to use this tables through relations table.

Comment: Also in Winforms it is a good idea to de-couple view and data layer by using view models. Just databind `Relation`s (which is a view model) and map back to the original entities when changes are committed. If you _really_ need two-way databinding you should bind the Id values and use lookup tables in combobox cells (show display value, bind Id value).

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but will need to use linq expression for each cell to find the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `entities.Relations.Select(r => new ...)` you are making a projection of each Relation EF object into a new non-EF object. By EF object I mean a class which is known by and tracked by EntityFramework.

Making changes to a EF-known class instance would propagate the changes back to DB when you save changes in your db/entity context. In contrast, making changes to a EF-unknown projection (or any projection) has no effect on the original object.

There are two ways you can achive what you want: If your DataGrid (NetAdvantage UltraGrid?) supports binding to subobjects (such as relation.device) you can then use `ultraGrid.DataSource = entities.relations` and define grid columns to bind to field `devices.device_name`. The other way would be something like this:

```
class Relation
{
    private readonly EfRelation _originalRelation;

    public Relation(EfRelation originalRelation)
    {
        this._originalRelation = originalRelation;
    }

    public string Devices 
    { 
        get { return this._originalRelation.devices.device_name; } 
        set { this._originalRelation.devices.device_name = value; } 
    }

    // Repeat for other properties
}

...

var reltables = entities.relations.ToList().Select(r => new Relation(r)).ToList();
```

Then you just save changes to your db/object context. The `EfRelation` is the name of your EF `Relation` class, change it to the name of your EF class which represents a relation.

Comment: Your way is clear but Linq doesn't let to use constructor.
also you say that can define columns to bind to fields. But how it possible in winFrom?

Comment: What do you mean? `entites.relations.OrderBy(r => r.id).Select(r => new Relation(r)).ToList()` must work.

Comment: Im sorry but not) Error: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

I have made the same with property instead of a constructor. All works fine. You are right , but not with constructor. Change your answer and I will set its to accept. Thanx

Comment: @Alex  Ah, I see. One ToList() call should take care of that :). Updated the answer.